# How to create tar archive without some folders?

Tags: linux, tar

How I can create tar archive without some folders?

Now I'm creating tar archive of folder and deleting some folders from it. But it is takes long time.

Structure:

www 
  - sub f 1
  - sub f 2
  - sub f 3

need create archive only with folders (sub f 1) and (sub f 2)
(It is only for example, my really structure have more sub levels)

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does this works ?

```
tar -cf backup.tar --exclude "www/subf3" www
// is your directory with spaces?
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition of the `--exclude` option suggested by  [Ajreal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8493063/841108), you could use some other `tar` option (from the `--help` output):

```
  --exclude=PATTERN      exclude files, given as a PATTERN
  --exclude-backups      exclude backup and lock files
  --exclude-caches       exclude contents of directories containing
                         CACHEDIR.TAG, except for the tag file itself
  --exclude-caches-all   exclude directories containing CACHEDIR.TAG
  --exclude-caches-under exclude everything under directories containing
                         CACHEDIR.TAG
  --exclude-tag=FILE     exclude contents of directories containing FILE,
                         except for FILE itself
  --exclude-tag-all=FILE exclude directories containing FILE
  --exclude-tag-under=FILE   exclude everything under directories
                         containing FILE
  --exclude-vcs          exclude version control system directories
-X, --exclude-from=FILE    exclude patterns listed in FILE
```

and you could also use [`tardy`](http://freecode.com/projects/tardy), a tar post-processor (which is [packaged in Debian](http://packages.debian.org/en/unstable//tardy))